# In VS 2008, how do I clear web.config for release build?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-config

I have my own personal information in web.config for debug build, now I need to do release build, how do I remove my own information from web.config?

Also, the release build also delete all the comment in web.config.  How do I include them?  I provide useful information in them to the client.

Answer (score -1):

Look here:

[ASP.NET 4.0, Part 4: Config Transformation Files](http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2010/02/17/ASPNET-40-Part-4-Config-Transformation-Files.aspx)

The post talks about Web Deployment Projects that can be used in VS 2008. It allows you to define post-build actions to change your web.config files content.

> An out-of-band release for VS2008 that appeared for download in
>   January 2008, a Web Deployment Project (WDP) provides a configurable
>   post-build step in VS2008 for web developers.